# Creating a Chat Room and Adding Users who are Not Registered Users

Tags: usability, mobile

**Background**

*Note: This isn't the actual type of app, it's just a similar situation.*

If I have a mobile chat app in which a user creates an account, creates a new conversation and is allowed to add others via email.  If the email does not belong to a user of the app, then an email will be sent to the person inviting him or her to sign up.  If the email belongs to a registered chat-app user, then he or she is just included, and like other chat apps the message will appear in the message list of the app.

**Question**

What should be the expected behavior in a scenario where the person who creates a new conversation and only adds emails that do not belong to any registered users?

Here are my thoughts so far.  I do not want to require the user to add at least 1 other person who is a member.  I also wanted to try to avoid having to have a list of "friends", and only allow them to start a conversation if they have 1 or more friends in their list.  The reason is that I did not want to implement a friend request/invitation system.  It's not a social network.

Comment: By saying you don't want to app a request-invitation saying you are implying that someone the email would servers not only as a invitation to join app but the only "gate" to start a conversation with the person who has invited you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your question exactly? If it's how to represent unregistered users in the app once a conversation has been set up, you can learn from any service that has a representation of unknown users. E.g. what Google Apps does when anonymous people are viewing a document (representing them by "[anonymous animals](http://googlesystem.blogspot.co.il/2013/04/anonymous-animals-in-google-drive.html)"). Or what this site does with non-registered posters (assigning them names like "user_6508798" and automatically generated generic avatars.  Or what web meeting services do when you're the first one to arrive - they say stuff like "No other attendees have arrived yet". You can say that the conversation is waiting for 3 more people to join, without listing their names.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of hard to have a conversation by yourself :) They can't really have a conversation until there is someone to talk to.

Maybe you can "request conversation" and it remains in the "request" state until someone joins - either a user who already has the app joins or someone who gets the email installs the app and joins.